# Getting session expired error when trying to load url in WKWebview but working fine in SFSafariViewController or external safari in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

My iOS app has a list of image thumbnails, on every click of thumbnail we are calling API to get the authenticated URL(eUnity Imageviewer URL) and url have 15 minutes session after that it will expire.

My question is when I am trying to load the url in `WKWebView`, first time it is opening properly when application is newly installed but once we opened that URL on `WKWebView` and we (killed/terminate/put in background) the app and when we come back to application it is giving error session expired for every thumbnail but same url is working fine in `SFSafariViewControlle`r or external safari. is `WKWebView` storing something??

I checked after clearing the `[WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes]`, `NSCachedURLResponse` and Allow Arbitrary Loads is also `YES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some research i found that by default WKWebView was storing cookies and session onto the disk so first set the `WKWebsiteDataStore` type as `nonPersistentDataStore` because by setting this property will not allow to store the data on disk

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *webConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
webConfiguration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistentDataStore;
webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:webConfiguration];
```

Then find and delete the stored cookies before the `[webView loadRequest:request]` method with below code

```
if (@available(iOS 9.0, *)) {
            NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *cookiesFolderPath = [libraryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/Cookies"];
    
            NSError *errors;
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:cookiesFolderPath error:&errors];
            
        } else {
    
            WKWebsiteDataStore *dateStore = [WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore];
            [dateStore fetchDataRecordsOfTypes:[WKWebsiteDataStore allWebsiteDataTypes] completionHandler:^(NSArray<WKWebsiteDataRecord *> * __nonnull records) {
    
                for (WKWebsiteDataRecord *record in records) {
                    NSLog(@"All records - %@ and data type - %@", record, record.dataTypes);
            
                    [[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:record.dataTypes forDataRecords:@[record] completionHandler:^{
                            NSLog(@"Cookies for %@ deleted successfully",record.displayName);
                    }];
                }
            }];
        }
```

This above solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need the WKWebView caching?

Frankly, for the most part we have had issues with using cache as the data that had to be flushed were persisted anyway leading to various bugs. Therefore we decided to ignore all cached data all together and it solved the caching bugs we have encountered.

When initializing the `NSURLRequest`, try to pass `NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData` as the `cachePolicy` parameter.

Alternatively you can try executing the code below, but beware, it removes cached responses from all the `NSURLRequests` from within the app.

`[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];`

In the `NSURLCache` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlcache?language=objc) you can check out alternatives to removing cached objects which might better suit your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Manually we are not caching anything in WKWebview and i have printed the Log to see the Cache, Cookies and any session data if available but nothing is there. I tried with your suggestions as well but no luck....Thanks